# Given a string I want to extract some text

Tags: excel, vba

Given a list of strings, I want to divide the strings into different columns. The strings does not always comes in the same format, so I cannot use the same approach each time. I am trying to put the LC-XXXXXX in column B, then delete the "s" and put the text after the "s" and between the "^" or the "." (whatever the string contains) into column C

I am running a "for loop" for each string in which is saved as an array and looks something like this:

I have use the split, trim and mid commands but with no success.

```
With Sheets("TELECOM")
.Range("A14", "I305").ClearContents
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
On Error Resume Next
    If InStr(objFile.Name, "LC-9") > 0 And InStr(objFile.Type, "DWG File") > 0 Then
        drwn = objFile.Name
        .Cells(r, 2) = Left(drwn, InStr(1, drwn, "s") - 1) 'Get the drawing number and placing it here
        values = Array(drwn)
        Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        pattern = "(s\d+)"
    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        .Cells(r, 3) = Replace$(drwn, "s", vbNullString)
    Next
    r = r + 1
    End With

    Public Function GetId(ByVal re As Object, ByVal s As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String
With re
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False '? True if case insensitive
    .pattern = pattern
    If .test(s) Then
        GetId = .Execute(s)(0).SubMatches(0)
    End If
End With
```

End Function

I would like to take the list of stings and put the LC-XXXXX in column B and the sheet number (numbers between the "s" and the "^" or sometimes the ".dwg" or ".pdf") into a column C

NEW EDIT 04/06/2019
[image]

New Edit 04/07/2019

Main Code
    Sub GetIssued()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object

```
Dim openPos As Integer
Dim closePos As Integer

Dim sh As Object

Dim drwn, SheetNum

Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")

r = 14


fle = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D11") &  
"\Design\Substation\CADD\Working\COMM\"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(fle)

Set x1Book = ActiveWorkbook 'Using this Activeworkbook
Set sh = x1Book.Sheets("TELECOM") 'Using this particular sheet
With Sheets("TELECOM")
.Range("A14", "I305").ClearContents
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
On Error Resume Next

If InStr(objFile.Name, "LC-9") > 0 And InStr(objFile.Type, "DWG                 
File") > 0 Then 'PEDs, Single Line, Cable and Wiring, Jumper and     
Interconnection
        .Cells(r, 9) = objFile.Name 'Testing Purposes
        drwn = Array(.Cells(r, 9).Value)
        .Cells(r, 2) = Left(drwn, InStr(1, drwn, "s") - 1) 'Get the 
drawing number and placing it here

        '-----------------------------------------------------------
        'Trying to Insert InstrMacro here
        '------------------------------------------------------------

        r = r + 1

        ElseIf InStr(objFile.Name, "MC-9") > 0 And InStr(objFile.Type, "DWG File") > 0 Then 'Cable List
        .Cells(r, 9) = objFile.Name 'Testing Purposes
        drwn = .Cells(r, 9).Value
        .Cells(r, 2) = Left(drwn, InStr(1, drwn, "s") - 1) 'Get the drawing number and placing it here 

        '-----------------------------------------------------------
        'Trying to Insert InstrMacro here
        '------------------------------------------------------------

        r = r + 1

        ElseIf InStr(objFile.Name, "BMC-") > 0 And InStr(objFile.Type, "Adobe Acrobat Document") > 0 Then 'Bill of Materials
        .Cells(r, 9) = objFile.Name 'Testing Purposes
        drwn = .Cells(r, 9).Value
        .Cells(r, 2) = Left(drwn, InStr(1, drwn, "s") - 1) 'Get the drawing number and placing it here 

        '-----------------------------------------------------------
        'Trying to Insert InstrMacro here
        '------------------------------------------------------------

        r = r + 1

        ElseIf InStr(objFile.Name, "CSR") > 0 And InStr(objFile.Type, "DWG") > 0 Then 'Single Line Diagram
        .Cells(r, 9) = objFile.Name 'Testing Purposes
        drwn = .Cells(r, 9).Value
        .Cells(r, 2) = Left(drwn, InStr(1, drwn, "s") - 1) 'Get the drawing number and placing it here

        '---------------------------------------------------------
        'Trying to Insert InstrMacro here
        '------------------------------------------------------------

        r = r + 1
    End If
Next
End With





 Range("A13:F305").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
 Range("A1").Select

 End Sub
```

The marco that I have working can be seen here:

```
Sub InstrMacro()

Dim openPos As Integer
Dim closePos As Integer

Dim drwn, SheetNum
drwn = Range("E9") ' String to search in the sheet aka: the hot seat


'Performing a test to see if this is a new drawing or not
SheetNum = InStr(drwn, "^")

openPos = InStr(drwn, "s") 'True reguardless of the condition of the drawing

If SheetNum = 0 Then 'Assuming it is a new drawing
closePos = InStr(drwn, ".")
SheetNum = Mid(drwn, openPos + 1, closePos - openPos - 1)
Else

If SheetNum > 0 Then 'Assuming is NOT a new drawing
closePos = InStr(drwn, "^")
SheetNum = Mid(drwn, openPos + 1, closePos - openPos - 1)

End If
End If

Range("G20").Value = SheetNum


End Sub
```

A picture for this macro can be seen here.

[image]

I have tried making a separate macro the runs and can get the sheet number, but it seems that excel is just skipping this step and running through the rest of the program

I would like to put the drawing number in column B and the sheet number in sheet number in column c.

Comment: Can s appear elsewhere in the string? If it does, will it be followed by a number? And when you say just s2 do you actually mean s followed by any number? Is that number always a single digit?

Comment: Not sure if you mean a pattern, or literally find just `s2` somewhere in the string. If that's what you want, try `Instr(1,MyFileName,"s2",vbTextCompare)` that will return an integer value with the starting position of the matching search value. Basically, if it returns more than 0, it is contained in the larger string.

Comment: @RyanWildry No I just need the numerical digits between the s and the  the "^" or the "." whichever the string contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is s followed by a number/numbers, and this pattern only occurs once, you could  use regex.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim re As Object, pattern As String, values(), i As Long
    values = Array("LC-94773s2^003735377.pdf", "LC-94773s2", "LC-93521s1-A^005241446")
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    pattern = "(s\d+)"
    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        Debug.Print Replace$(GetId(re, values(i), pattern), "s",vbNullString)
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetId(ByVal re As Object, ByVal s As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False '? True if case insensitive
        .pattern = pattern
        If .test(s) Then
            GetId = .Execute(s)(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            GetId = "No match"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

---

You can vary this pattern, for example, if want start to be `LC-9`

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim re As Object, pattern As String, values(), i As Long
    values = Array("LC-94773s2^003735377.pdf", "LC-94773s2", "LC-93521s1-A^005241446")
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    pattern = "LC-9(.*)(s\d+)"
    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        Debug.Print Replace$(GetId(re, values(i), pattern), "s",vbNullString)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Using the first code, this keeps returning the sheet number with a "s" Is there a way to delete and get the just the text after the "s"?

Comment: See edit to answer. I will also update at some point regex as can remove the s there also.

Comment: Almost got it...I know this wasn't included in my original question, but if I had a string that started with MC-XXXXXXsTCV4, can I just get this to return the TCV4 too? @QHarr

Comment: What is the pattern and the desired return string? Surely not just TCV4 but TCV4, TCV5 or some such pattern and starts with MC-

Comment: Its the same as the LC-XXXXX. I am wanting the final result to look something like the new picture I posted in my question. (I couldn't upload it to this comment, so I am posting it there.)

Comment: you can change pattern to "MC-(.*)(TCV\d+)" and in the function use GetId = .Execute(s)(0).SubMatches(1)

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191412/discussion-between-christopher-lee-and-qharr).

Comment: Not just yet. I still have the drawing number that is listed in column B, but I still cannot get the sheet number and put this in column C. I wrote a separate macro to get the sheet number (that works fine), which I would like to incorporate into my main code. However when I do this it seems that excel is just getting the drawing number and skipping over the sheet number. I have updated my question to include my main code and the separate marco which I would like to incorporate.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with no loops nor regex

```
Sub FindIt()
    Dim strng As String, iPos As Long

    strng= "1sa2sb3s4sd5se"

    iPos = InStr(strng, "s")
    If iPos > 0 And iPos < Len(strng) Then
        If InStr("1234567890", Mid(strng, iPos + 1, 1)) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Found s" & Mid(strng, iPos + 1,1) & " at position " & iPos
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Which can be easily twicked to limit the number of numeric digits following the “s” character

Answer (score 0):

To see if a string contains a lower case *s* followed by a numeral:

```
Sub sTest()
    Dim s As String, i As Long
    s = "jkuirelkjs6kbco82yhgjbc"

    For i = 0 To 9
        If InStr(s, "s" & CStr(i)) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "I found s" & i & " at position " & InStr(s, "s" & CStr(i))
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox "pattern not found"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    arr = Array("LC-94773s2^003735377.pdf", "LC-94773s2", "Mar", "LC-93521s1-A^005241446")

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If InStr(1, arr(i), "s") Then
            Debug.Print Mid(arr(i), InStr(1, arr(i), "s"), 2)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```